# Busca por relacionamento Laravel whereHas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma `Query` no meu `Criteria` que retorna os `id` pertencentes ao ***relacionamento*** entre `models`

```
if ($this->request->has('notin_portal')) 
{
    $portal = $this->request->get('notin_portal');
    if ($this->request->get('notin_portal')) 
    {
         $model = $model->whereHas('portals', function($query) use ($portal)
         {
              $query->where('id', $portal);
         });
         return $model;
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que eu preciso retornar os `ids` que NÃO pertencem ao relacionamento `portals` nas models. ***Existe algo do tipo***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é só colocar `<>` no [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

***Exemplo***

```
$query->where('id', '<>', $portal);
```

Também ***existe*** a maneira de comparar com [`whereIn` / `whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

***Exemplos:***

```
->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3]);
```

---

```
->whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3]);
```

no seu caso também funcionaria [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Com [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) também pode satisfazer essa pesquisa:

***Exemplo***

```
->whereRaw("id <> {$portal}");
```

Na versão mais atual pode utilizar [`whereDoesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

***Exemplo:***

```
$model = $model->whereDoesntHave('portals', function ($query) use ($portal)
{
    $query->where('id', $portal);
});
```